# OneSplit (Web3.py) - How to get the exact price of a pair on 1inch?

Tags: web3js, python, price

the title explain itself, im using the OneSplit contract to get the price of a pair in 1inch. But the whole point is that i used getExpectedReturn correctly but it returns a value with no decimals and its not really that useful for me. Is there any way i can get more precision? Code i've made:

```
# Gets the 1inch DAO price for ETH
token2_checksum = w3.toChecksumAddress("0x6B175474E89094C44DA98B954EEDEAC495271D0F")
oneinchETHPRICE = exchange_contract.functions.getExpectedReturn(
"0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE",
    token2_checksum, 
    1,
    1,
    1,
).call()

def oneinch_ETH_DAI():
    print(oneinchETHPRICE)
oneinch_ETH_DAI()
```

And it returns for example 3990, but what i want is 3990.3289482948329 (example).

Thanks for reading, <3

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version you are working with but my call only take 3 arguments.

```
const oneSplitData = await fetchOneSplitData({
      fromToken: assetOrder[1],                   // from the quoted asset
      toToken: assetOrder[2],                     // back to Loan asset/base asset
      amount: zrxOrder.makerAssetAmount,          // The amount     
    })
```

The amount should be provided in WEI

1 ETH (18 decimals) = "1000000000000000000"  <-- it's a string

1 DAI is the same.

I'm not sure what the 2 other 1, 1 are for since my call don't require them

By adding all the 0 you should get an accurate reading.

I use ethers.io to parse my numbers. Take a look at the parseEher / formatUnit method.

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseEther

Not 100% sure that 1Inch use

"0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE"

for eth. I know Matic does.

Comment: Thanks cuh, but is this python? Also where is fetchOneSplitData function on the OneSplitAudit contract? Kinda confused.